# Initialization of fields of class

Tags: java, oop, constructor

Sorry, if this question is trivial...

There are two ways of initializing fields

For example:

The first way is:

```
Public class A{
    int a;
    A(){
        a = 5;
    }
}
```

The second way is:

```
Public class A{
    int a = 5;
    A(){
    }
}
```

Which way is better? Why or why not?

Comment: Whether you initialize or not primitive int is always '0'. Coming to declaration if you are sticking with a constant default value initializing during the declaration is preferred. If you want the value to be passed while initializing the object then use the constructor.

Comment: Instance variable are by default initialized. its zero for int.

Comment: @Braj what if the a = 5 at the beginning?

Comment: My mistake, I looked at the answer first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both ways are correct.

Prefer second way if you don't want to repeat the code as shown in below code:

```
public class A{
    int a;
    A(){
       a=5;
    }
    A(String s){
       a=5;
    }
    A(Long l){
       a=5;
    }
 }

 public class A{
    int a = 5;
    A(){
    }
    A(String s){
    }
    A(Long l){
    }
 }
```

In the second case you don't have to initialize it for all the overloaded constructor.

Now it depends on your choice.

Comment: I like this reason: "Prefer second way if you don't want to repeat the code as shown in below code"

Comment: Instead of A(String a), i think it should be A(int a) { this.a = a; }. Please check

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you want.

If you only have one constructor, then it doesn't matter, because either way the value will start a 0. If you have more than one constructor, it still doesn't really matter, but it might be better to do it the following way:

```
int a;

A() {
    a = 0;
}

A(int newA) {
    a = newA;
}
```

When I personally develop, I will assign the value at the top in the following cases only:

1. The variable I am assigning is a constants.
2. The variable has some sort of **default** value, that can and usually will change.